# DomDocument loading div html by id using nodevalue

Tags: php, html, domdocument

as the title says I'm trying to get code from  with id counterResult it's an external website this is my code so far:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($url);
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$resultCounter = $doc->getElementById('resultCounter');
echo $resultCounter->nodeValue;
```

The error that I get on the last line (with echo) is ) Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\wheelofporn\test.php on line 10

Comment: I guess `nodeValue` doesnt exists... Trying `echo '<pre>; 'print_r($doc);`...you will get to know whether `nodeValue` exists or not...and comment the `$resultCounter` and echo statement..

Comment: not sure that can be done using a url like that